# MFC - Change font in a CMFCToolTipCtrl used in CDialogEx control

Tags: c++, mfc, tooltip

I'm trying to display a ToolTip for a CStatic derived control in my dialog.

What I've already done:

1. Added a CMFCToolTipCtrl item to my CDialogEx member.
2. In the init dialog member I've specified CMFCToolTipInfo structure and passed it as argument in CMFCToolTipCtrl item constructor.
3. Call the EnableToolTips(); member for my CStaticExts and for my CDialogEx.
4. Overrided the PreTranslateMessage of my CDialogEx adding the "RelayEvent".
5. Set "Notify: TRUE" in the resource editor.

Doing so I managed to display the tooltip in a partially customized way (baloon and background color) but now I would like to enlarge the font, make it bold and, eventually, display an icon, similarly to the tool tips I can see on my toolbar.

I already tried calling "SetFont" and "SetIcon" methods for the CMFCToolTipCtrl item but it didn't work.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal Font that is used in CMFCToolTipCtrl ist retrieved from a global data store inside the MFC (see GetGlobalData()->fontTooltip). This data structure AFX_GLOBAL_DATA is filled when the MFC is started. SetFont has no effect here.

If you want to change the behaviour you have to create your own CMFCToolTipCtrl class and overwrite OnDrawLabel. You have the source of the MFC so it is easy to provide your own implementation.